# How close a crewed spacecraft could orbit Jupiter?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, radiation, jupiter

How close could a crewed spacecraft orbit Jupiter?

I read that Juno was as close as 5,000 km from Jupiter's top clouds, but I'm wondering about a spacecraft with humans inside (provided it's protected from radiation).

Comment: Protecting the crew from radiation will be a major shielding design challenge and will make the capsule very different than ones useful in cis-lunar space. So the parenthetical statement "(provided it's protected from radiation)" excludes a really major factor. Jupiter's [scale height]() is [27 km](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/jupiterfact.html) about 4x larger than Earth's so drag needs to be considered. Are you assuming an infinite supply of massless nutrition and 100% efficient recycling of waste and CO2?

Comment: @uhoh thanks for your answer; yes.

Comment: --- Anybody? ----

Comment: What's the extension of the inner and outer van allen belts of jupiter? from what to what altitude?

Comment: @Pablo that's a totally different question. Maybe a question like "what are the major challenges a (crewed) spacecraft must overcome in order to orbit Jupiter in close proximity, and how might a spacecraft reasonably overcome these?" May be on topic? (I'm not sure)

Comment: The inner limit depends strongly on the angle from the equatorial plane (the equivalent of latitude). It's about 1.4 Jupiter radii at the magnetic equatorial plane (which is tilted ~10° from the rotational equatorial plane) and gets closer as you go toward the poles. The outer limit, in the magnetic equatorial plane, depends on the level of solar activity and the angle to the Jupiter-sun vector, closer to Jupiter in the direction of the sun, farther as you go toward Jupiter's "magnetotail". The solar wind pushes the sun-side limit to ~15 Jupiter radii, about the orbit of Ganymede.